# 2- and 3-body problems when gravity is not inverse-square

Tags: classical-mechanics, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations, reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems

Suppose that gravity did not follow an inverse-square law, but was instead a central force diminishing
as $1/d^p$ for distance separation $d$ and some power $p$.
Two questions:

1. Presumably the 2-body problem still factors into two independent 1-body problems, 
   results in planar motion, and can be solved.  Have the orbits (the equivalents of elliptical and parabolic orbits for $p=2$) been worked out for other (perhaps specific) values of $p$?
2. In some sense, the 3-body problem for $p=2$ cannot be solved.
   Most systems are
   choatic; see [this interesting collection](http://faculty.ifmo.ru/butikov/Projects/Collection.html) of Eugene Butikov.
   Only a few periodic solutions are known;
   see the nice [article](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-orbits1) by Bill Casselman on the discovery of "choreographies."
   Is the situation simpler for other values of $p$?  Perhaps $p=1$?

References and pointers would be appreciated.  Thanks!

**Edit**. Thanks to Agol, Ken, and José. I've now looked at Arnolʹd's *Huygens* and Needham
(but not yet Arnolʹd's *Classical Mechanics*).  Indeed, as the commenters say, there is a remarkable 
2-body result for $p=1$: the orbits for a linearly attractive force are ellipses, for a linearly repulsive force, hyperbolae.  This depends on the Kasner-Arnolʹd theorem stating that for each power law, there is a *dual* power law that maps orbits of one to orbits of the other. Newton proved in *Principia* that elliptical orbits result if and only if the force is inverse-linear or inverse-square. The Kasner-Arnolʹd theorem explains why.

Comment: @Agol: Thanks for the reference! I am not familiar with Arnolʹd's *Huygens and Barrow, Newton and Hooke*, but I see that my college library has it, so I can retrieve it later. 

Comment: There's more on the 2-body case in Needhams' Visual Complex Analysis Book, see pp. 241-247.  There, he refers to Arnol'd's work, but also mentions that Arnol'd rediscovered the general result of E. Kasner in Kasner's 1913 work Differential-Geometric Aspects of Dynamics.

Comment: @Ken: Great!  I'll check out Needham as well.  Thanks!

Comment: If I remember correctly, for the 2-body problem, Arnold showed that the orbits are also ellipses (maybe for p=-1?) in the appendix of his book: http://books.google.com/books?id=1cP8sK-TviYC&lpg=PP1&dq=arnold%20newton%20hooke&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q&f=false I don't have access to the book now, so I can't quite remember what he proved. (I reposted this because the link was wrong).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answers to question (1)  for the 2 body problem are fine, and complete enough.

Regarding (2).  The 3 body problem (and N-body) with p =3 is significantly simpler
than with  $p \ne 3$.  The added simplicity is   due to the
occurenc  of an additional integral  which comes out of the Lagrange Jacobi identity
for the evolution of the total moment of inertia $I$.  This identity asserts
that $d^2 I/ dt^2 = 4 H + (4 - 2(p-1)) U$ where $H = K - U$ is the total energy,
with $K$ the kinetic energy and $U$ the NEGATIVE of the total potential energy,
a function which is homogeneous of degree $p-1$. When $p =3$ we get
$d^2 I/ dt^2 = 4H = const.$!.
(The total moment of inertia
is a the squared norm relative to the ``mass inner product' and as such
measures the total size of the system. )

For details on this Lagrange-Jacobi identity and its 
use see the first sections of my paper
`Hyperbolic Pants fit a three-body problem', Ergodic Theory and Dynamical Systems, Volume 25, - June 2005, 921-947, which you can also find on my web site 
http://count.ucsc.edu/~rmont/papers/list.html
or on the arXivs.  Also see the references there.

For a study of choreographies with various $p$- potentials see the paper by Fujiwara et al.
`Choreographic Three Bodies on the Lemniscate':J. Phys. A: Math. Gen. 36 (21 March 2003) 2791-2800, available on his web site ( or the ArXivs).
http://www.clas.kitasato-u.ac.jp/~fujiwara/nBody/nbody.html

The discoverer of the figure eight, Cris Moore,  in his beautiful
2 page paper `Braids and Classical Gravity'
(which Casselman should have a ref. to) found numerically, and argues
convincingly that  as one increases $p$ more and more ``braid types'' (and hence choreographies) appear. It is known that
all possible braid  types (and so choreography types) occur as soon as $p =2$.

The cases $p \ge 2$ are often called ``strong-force potentials'' and from the
variational perspective are much simpler than $p < 2$ for the reason that
with the strong force potentials all collision paths have infinite action.
This fact regarding action is surprising, since with the strong force condition in
force it seems that almost all bounded solutions end in collision. This "seems"  is a
theorem for the 2-body problem, and for the negative energy three body problem
when $p=2$.

Comment: Very interesting (and counterintuitive to naïve me) that strong force potentials are simpler.  Thanks for this rich collection of information!

Answer (score 8):

Not a complete answer, but there is a theorem (proved, for instance, in Arnold's *Mathematical Methods in Classical Mechanics*) that says that the only radial potentials for which all bound orbits are closed are the Kepler potential $\propto 1/r$ and the harmonic oscillator $\propto r^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer but too long for a comment.

In addition to the cases already mentioned, there is a third one where the orbits can be described simply in analytical terms.  This is where the force is proportional to $\frac 1{r^3}$---the curves are then Cotes spirals.  These three cases were known to Newton.

Maclaurin then discovered a two parameter family of orbits for each power law.  They are obtained from the Maclaurin spirals (as they are now known), i.e., the curves $r^n=\cos (n \theta)$---by dilation and rotation.  If $n$ is a whole number, then these orbits are closed---this is not in contradition to Bertrand's theorem, of course.

The reason for this is that the functions $(\cos (d \theta))^{\frac 1 d}$ are such that $f+f''$ is proportional to a power of $f$.

This fact lies  behind further remarkable properties of these curves (for example, their curvatures are proportional to a power of the distance from the origin and they are catenaries for suitable power laws (the index of the power law depends in a simple 
fashion on $d$).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding question 1):

a) In addition to the potentials for which all bound orbits are closed there are further central force potentials with analytic solutions, please cf.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem#Central_forces_with_exact_solutions
(Sorry, not quite what you were asking for [I read too fast], but perhaps interesting nevertheless.)

b) Perhaps this paper on "Multiparticle systems with a
particle-interaction potential homogeneous of degree α = −2" by Borisov et al. is interesting for you: http://ics.org.ru/doc?pdf=1359&dir=e. ("Some new integrable and superintegrable systems generalizing the classical ones are also described.").

Comment: "A central-force problem is said to be *integrable* if this integration [of the Binet equation] can be solved in terms of known functions."  Great, thanks Andreas! 

Answer (score 1):

A couple of Don Saari's papers from the 1970's era look at p = 2 + epsilon and show that there is no dramatic change in dynamics for a small perturbation of the exponent.